# Как правильно передать путь к файлу в функцию open() python

Tags: python, python-3.11

Нужна помощь более опытных в этом деле людей. Занимаюсь автоматизацией тестирования. И возник вопрос.
У меня есть структура проекта:

```
My first project
    Test results
    Studying project
        Tests
```

В папке Test хранятся тесты. При прохождении этих тестов, я хочу отлавливать ошибки, которые возникают в консоли при прохождении тестов и записывать их в файлик, который называется скажем console_errors.txt и помещать этот файлик в папку Tests results.

С помощью конструкции

```
with open(‘Test results/results.txt’, ‘a+’) as file:
    file.write(error msg)
```

я пытаюсь открыть этот файлик и записать в него данные. Ну либо же, как в моем случае, создать его, потому что в папке Tests results такого файлика нет и на каждый прогон тестов будет новый файлик.

Но когда я запускаю тесты из папки Tests, то у меня падает ошибка, что такого файла или каталога не существует. Я закинул в переменную путь к этой папке Tests results, чтобы через дебаггер посмотреть, почему ругается. И оказалось, что пайтон строит мне такой путь:

> My first project/Studying project/Tests/Tests results/results.txt

То есть он пытается найти папку Test results внутри папки Tests, хотя она на уровень выше.
Я даже пробовал через **os** получить абсолютный путь к папке Tests results и передать в функцию **open()** абсолютный путь, но питон подменяет его на кривой такого типа:

> D:/Autotests/My first project/Studying project/Tests/Tests results/results.txt

и снова не может найти папку.
Подскажите, как передать путь так, чтобы при запуске тестов из папки Tests, питон не искал папку Tests results внутри папки Tests и не ругался на меня, что такого пути нет.

Буду рад любой помощи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> То есть он пытается найти папку Test results внутри папки Tests, хотя она на уровень выше.

Код понятия не имеет, какие у вас там папки на уровень выше. Почему вы вдруг подумали, что он будет использовать какую-то папку по соседству? А если у вас на диске еще несколько папок с таким же названием, то что должен был бы делать код?

Ищется не папка `Test results`, которая у вас в папке `My first project`, а папка `Test results`, которая записана в строчке `with open(‘Test results/results.txt’, ‘a+’) as file` (кстати, это нерабочий код, потому что неправильные кавычки). Это разные `Test results`, которые не имеют ничего общего, кроме названия, и если бы вы назвали их по-разному, то сразу бы увидели корень проблемы.

Строчка `with open(‘Test results/results.txt’, ‘a+’) as file` открывает файл по указанному пути относительно той папки, в которой находится скрипт. Скрипт находится в папке

```
D:/Autotests/My first project/Studying project/Tests
```

поэтому полный путь к файлу получается

```
D:/Autotests/My first project/Studying project/Tests/Tests results/results.txt
```

Все так, как и должно быть.

Нужно в пути добавить уровень выше (или даже два)

```
with open(‘../Test results/results.txt’, ‘a+’) as file
```

И исправить кавычки на правильные.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек. 
Я изначально вроде уже пробовал такой вариант, но я точно был уверен, что он не сработал. А сейчас попробовал еще раз с ../ и получилось. 
В общем спасибо большое!!